# Understanding interim analysis and alpha spending functions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, clinical-trials, ab-test, sequential-analysis

I have to perform an A/B test with interim analysis and found some literature about methods designed to preserve the global Type I error rate by adjusting the $\alpha$ level for each peeking.

Examples include: Pocock, O'Brien-Fleming, Haybittle-Peto, and the concept of $\alpha$ spending function introduced by Lan-DeMets.

A central concept is that of dividing $\alpha$ among the different peekings. Yet, when summing the interim $\alpha$ levels, one always gets a level higher than the desired global Type I error rate.

Let us take for instance the Pocock boundaries for 5 peekings and with a global Type I error rate of 0.05. It is equal to 0.0158. But $5\times 0.0158 > 0.05$.

I understand that summing the interim $\alpha$ levels would constitute some sort of Bonferroni correction, which is too conservative.
So those methods all manage to perform better than this naive correction.

**Is there any proof, for any of these methods, that the desired global Type I error rate is preserved?**
I haven't found any in the relevant literature.